# JTable vertical size based on rows

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I'm insert the `JTable` database and getting the print.
In some cases it can fill up to 5 lines and in some cases 100 lines. When there are many lines, print does not appear.
My goal is to increase the length of the table based on the number of rows and view without needing `JScrollPane`.

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: A jtable without a jscrollpane will look weird, i.e. no headers.

Comment: [mcve] please demonstrating what you want to achieve and how it doesn't work. Aside: I'm aware that spelling in a foreign language might be tricky (me getting it wrong more often than not ;) but technical terms should be correct, it's JTable (not jatble :)

Answer (score 1):

> My goal is to increase the length of the table based on the number of rows. view without needing JScrollPane

Easy way is to use the scroll pane:

```
JTable table = new JTable(model);
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
```

Now the table will be the same size as the scroll pane so no scrollbars will appear and the table header will be displayed. If you add the scroll pane to a panel that respects the preferred size of the scroll pane then you will see all the rows.

Or, another option is to build your own panel using a BorderLayout. Then you do:

```
panel.add(table.getHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
panel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```